# bind a checkboxlist using knockoutjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I'm trying to bind a checkboxlist using knockoutjs.
I have a user related to a list of profiles, what I want is when the page is loaded to init the checkboxlist with the user profiles.

This is my code

```
var userProfileList = [];
var jsonUserAdminModel = null;
var viewModel = {
    ,firstName: ko.observable()
    ,lastName: ko.observable()
    ,userId: ko.observable()
    ,userProfiles: ko.observableArray(userProfileList)
    ,result: ko.observable()
};

viewModel.result = ko.computed(function () {
    jsonUserAdminModel = {
        UserId: (this.userId() != undefined ? this.userId() : null)
        ,FirstName: (this.firstName() != undefined ? this.firstName() : null)
        ,LastName: (this.lastName() != undefined ? this.lastName() : null)            
    }
    return jsonUserAdminModel;
}, viewModel);

$(document).ready(function () {               
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        //Init the list of all profiles
        viewModel.userProfiles(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Profiles)));
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="UserProfiles" data-bind="foreach: userProfiles" style="margin: 10px">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: ProfileId" /><span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
</div>
```

I want to check the user default profiles and bind it.

Thanks.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here.

Comment: Please share the jsFiddle for this, it would be easy to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to bind your input to a `checked` [observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) on the user profile object. To do that, you're going to need to create a profile viewmodel and convert your raw data into instances of that viewmodel so that their properties can be made observable. You could also use the [`ko.mapping`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin to achieve this.

Then your HTML would look something like this:

```
<div id="UserProfiles" data-bind="foreach: userProfiles" style="margin: 10px">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: {value: ProfileId() }, checked: isChecked" /><span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
</div>
```